# If the target of Brutish Shove dies, can I still shove (and follow) it?

Tags: fighter, pathfinder-2e

If a fighter with the Feat [Brutish Shove](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=365) uses an action to use Brutish Shove and hits, but the target dies from the hit, can the fighter still shove the (now dead) target for the purpose of following its corpse and thus moving a bit?

I don't see anything in the rules that forbids this, except maybe that Shove references a "creature", and a corpse might no longer be a creature? But on the other hand, the Shove from Brutish Shove is triggered on a hit, so can it be used before damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes, you can shove it.**

The brutish shove feat never talks about damage but only on hitting a creature so, the trigger, it is the fact that you have hit your enemy and not the fact that you have dealt damage.

This is important because it means that **even if you deal zero damage** (eg: enemy damage resistance absorbs your damage) you will shove your target anyway.

> Make a Strike with a two-handed melee weapon. If you hit a target that is your size or smaller, that creature is flat-footed until the end of your current turn, and you can automatically Shove it, with the same benefits as the Shove action (including the critical success effect, if your Strike was a critical hit).

To be more clear the steps are:

- Roll to Hit
- Any effect triggered by a 'hit' (eg: [Critical Specialization Effects](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=235), Brutish Shove and so on)
- Roll to Damage (You can find here how the damage functions: [Damage steps](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=335))
- Any effect triggered by a 'damage dealt' (eg: Damage resistances, [Retributive Pain](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=447) and so on)

Last but not least: yes, you can not shove a dead target (but how explained above *this is not the case*)

**Tl,dr:** Brutish Shove trigger on a 'hit' so **you will always shove the target if you want and if the target is of the right size**.

Comment: Where does the ordering of steps come from? (Specifically, where does the separation of the "Roll To Damage" and "effects triggered by a hit" come from?)

Comment: Well to hit something is different to damage something and actually, in one of the link I provided, we can see that damage have it's own steps. The rest is logic: you first hit something and only after apply damage to it. Another clear hint that hitting something is a different trigger from dealing damage to something is provided by how feats, spells and so on are written. Put in another way: if you hit something but an enemy resistance bring the total damage to zero..the 'Strike' action you used is still a success and therefore all effect related to strike/hit are applied (like a frost rune).

Comment: But since damage is bring to zero by the enemy resistance you deal no damage with that successful strike. Therefore all effects triggered by a successfull strike happens but all effects triggered by dealing damage to something are not since there was no damage at all at the end of the damage flow steps.